# Routing in the WebApiConfig

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.Net. Just started learning on creating Web APIs. Below is the Hello World example I am trying to execute. I am using visual studio 2013.

Below is my controller class.

```
public class HW : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string SayHello()
    {  
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

My question is, How do I route web request, so as it maps to SayHello method.

This is what I am currently configuring in WebApiConfig.cs for mapping

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "HW", action = "SayHello", id =   RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I am getting "No type was found that matches the controller named HW" as error.

If I use Route annotation it works.

[Route("api/HW/SayHello")]

Answer (score 0):

MVC works using naming conventions. One of these conventions is that controller names end Controller. So when your route states `controller = "HW"` a controller called HWController is expected.

If you rename your controller from HW to HWController it should work.

Comment: I made that change. Renamed it HWController. Still the same. My webAPI call looks like this:

http://localhost:52242/api/HWController/SayHello